# Java Fx Tableview population cannot retrieve property

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, scenebuilder

I have a table view which I have populated with information by button, however while I can select the rows which hold data, the text is not visible.

```
public class Account {
    private SimpleStringProperty Col_id, Col_name, Col_surname, Col_phone;
    
    public Account(String id, String name, String surname, String phone) {
        this.Col_id = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
        this.Col_name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.Col_surname = new SimpleStringProperty(surname);
        this.Col_phone = new SimpleStringProperty(phone);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Col_id.get();
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.Col_id.set(id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Col_name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Col_name.set(name);
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return Col_surname.get();
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.Col_surname.set(surname);
    }

    public String getNum() {
        return Col_phone.get();
    }

    public void setNum(String num) {
        this.Col_phone.set(num);
    }
}
```

and here is my controller:

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {
    
    
        @FXML
        private Button btnAccount, btnCustomer, btnBook, btnExit, btnAddPerson, btnAddBook, btnAddCustomer;
        @FXML
        private GridPane pnAccount, pnCustomer, pnBook;
        @FXML
        private Pane pnlStatus;
        @FXML
        private Label lblStatus, lblWelcome;    
        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> boxCustomer, boxBook;
        @FXML
        private TextField txtName,txtSurname,txtPhone, txtBookName,txtAuthor,txtCustomerId,txtBookId;
        @FXML
        private DatePicker processDate;
        @FXML
        private TableView<Account> tablePerson;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Account, String> id;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Account, String> name;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Account, String> surname;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Account, String> phone;
    
        
        @FXML
        private TableView<Book> tableBook;
        
        @FXML
        private TableView<Customer> tableCustomer;
        
        @FXML
        private void handleClicks (ActionEvent event) {
        
        lblStatus.setVisible(true);
        pnlStatus.setVisible(true);
        lblWelcome.setVisible(false);
        
        if(event.getSource() == btnAccount){
            
            lblStatus.setText("Create Account");
            pnAccount.setVisible(true);
            pnBook.setVisible(false);
            pnCustomer.setVisible(false);
        }
    
        
    @FXML
    private void clickAddPerson(ActionEvent event) {
        event.consume();
        int id = Main.getRandomNumberUsingNextInt(000000, 999999);
        boolean check = true;
        while(check) {
            String s=String.valueOf(id);
            check = Main.checkAccountId(s);
            if(check == false) {
                Account account = new Account(s,txtName.getText(), txtSurname.getText(), txtPhone.getText());
                Main.accounts.add(account);
                tablePerson.getItems().add(account);
            }
        }

        
    }
```

Also my fxml

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="-2.0" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="337.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3F2B63;">
         <children>
            <Pane prefHeight="207.0" prefWidth="337.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="63.0" fitWidth="208.0" layoutX="137.0" layoutY="34.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@literature-xxl.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label layoutX="82.0" layoutY="104.0" text="Bookstore" textFill="WHITE">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children></Pane>
            <Button fx:id="btnAccount" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClicks" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="338.0" styleClass="sidebarItem" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Create Account" textFill="WHITE">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="25.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@add-user-xxl.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btnCustomer" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClicks" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="337.0" styleClass="sidebarItem" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Transactions" textFill="WHITE">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="25.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@banknotes-xxl.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btnBook" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClicks" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="337.0" styleClass="sidebarItem" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Book List" textFill="WHITE">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="25.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@books-xxl.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btnExit" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClicks" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="337.0" styleClass="sidebarItem" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Exit" textFill="WHITE">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="50.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="25.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@close-window-xxl.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <StackPane layoutX="341.0" layoutY="336.0">
         <children>
            <GridPane fx:id="pnCustomer" prefHeight="345.0" prefWidth="691.0" visible="false">
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="113.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="32.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="300.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="300.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tableCustomer" prefHeight="209.0" prefWidth="732.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Customer ID" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Book ID" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Type" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Date" />
                     </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
                  <HBox prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="699.0" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="txtCustomerId" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="237.0" promptText="Customer ID" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <TextField fx:id="txtBookId" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="249.0" promptText="Book ID" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="boxCustomer" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Type" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <DatePicker fx:id="processDate" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="229.0" promptText="Date" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnAddCustomer" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickAddCustomer" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="223.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3F2B63;" text="Approve" textFill="WHITE">
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="12.0" fitWidth="11.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@plus-2-xxl.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
            <GridPane fx:id="pnBook" prefHeight="345.0" prefWidth="691.0" visible="false">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="113.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="32.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="300.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="300.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tableBook" prefHeight="209.0" prefWidth="732.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Book Name" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Writer" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Category" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Stock" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
                  <HBox prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="699.0" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="txtBookName" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="408.0" promptText="Book Name" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <TextField fx:id="txtAuthor" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="245.0" promptText="Writer" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="boxBook" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="211.0" promptText="Category" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnAddBook" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickAddBook" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="223.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3F2B63;" text="Add Book" textFill="WHITE">
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="12.0" fitWidth="11.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@plus-2-xxl.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
            <GridPane fx:id="pnAccount" prefHeight="359.0" prefWidth="738.0" visible="false">
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="113.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="32.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="300.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="300.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tablePerson" prefHeight="154.0" prefWidth="743.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="id" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="name" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="surname" prefWidth="75.0" text="Surname" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="phone" prefWidth="75.0" text="Phone Number" />
                     </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
                  <HBox prefHeight="103.0" prefWidth="718.0" spacing="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="txtName" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="206.0" promptText="Name" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <TextField fx:id="txtSurname" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="194.0" promptText="Surname" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <TextField fx:id="txtPhone" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="146.0" promptText="Phone" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #3F2B63;" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnAddPerson" graphicTextGap="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clickAddPerson" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3F2B63;" text="Add Account" textFill="WHITE">
                           <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="12.0" fitWidth="11.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@plus-2-xxl.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </graphic>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <Pane fx:id="pnlStatus" layoutX="334.0" layoutY="107.0" prefHeight="166.0" prefWidth="746.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3F2B63;" visible="false">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblStatus" layoutX="41.0" layoutY="46.0" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="415.0" text="Book List" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="48.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <Label fx:id="lblWelcome" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="511.0" layoutY="305.0" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="398.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3F2B63;" text="Welcome to bookstore system" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

As i said i can add account with filled info. İt populates the lines. But its blank.

It seems it cannot retrieve property of Id, name, surname, phone any tips?^^

Comment: anyway - as already suggested in a comment to your previous question: [mcve] required (mind the __M__!)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set cellValueFactory for each column in your controller (maybe during initialization).

Something like below:

```
id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Account, StringProperty>("id"));
```

Comment: Better to recommend the OP have `Account` expose the properties (via typical JavaFX-style "property getters") and then use a lambda to implement the cell value factory (e.g. `id.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().idProperty())`). That avoids reflection and gives compile-time safety.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem on reddit post. Here if the fix anyone encountered same problem.

add this to model-info.java

"opens application to fxml, javafx.base"

Comment: If that was the solution then you should have been getting an error at run-time. Someone would have been able to help you more quickly and more accurately if you had provided us with that error. If and when you ask another question in the future, please make sure your question meets the guidelines presented by the [ask] page and that you provide a [mre].